# Jenkins Build Hangs on Post Build Task

Tags: linux, jenkins, asp.net-core

I have a freestyle project in Jenkins that builds and deploys an ASP.Net Core application. When an agent executes a build, it always hangs on a post build script, which is used to start the application.

```
# Start the application
cd /
cd 'var/www/TestApp'
dotnet 'TestApp.dll'
```

The script works as expected and starts the application, but the build never progresses past this point.

I'm assuming the issue is related to the process the script starts, base on what I'm seeing in the console output.

```
Running script  : # Start the application
cd /
cd 'var/www/TestApp'
dotnet 'TestApp.dll'
[Test App] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1739214043299588563.sh
+ cd /
+ cd var/www/TestApp
+ dotnet TestApp.dll
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /var/www/TestApp
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

My question is where should I start the application, so it doesn't hang the build.

Comment: What happens if you run the app in the background and output to a log file instead of console ?

Comment: @ben5556, do you know how to suppress Jenkins' console output?

Comment: http://kagarlickij.com/run-dotnet-core-apps-without-console-output/

Comment: I'm trying to run a compiled application, so that method won't work. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm not a linux guy, but according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/run-a-command-without-making-me-wait) thread you need to append & at the end to run the command in the background. Try `dotnet 'TestApp.dll' &` and let me know how did it go.